# Why can I not install in the certain order?

Tags: installation, installshield

I have two installers and one patch. They have the same upgrade code but different product code like below.

> ```
>             Version           ProductCode     UpgradeCode
> ```
>
> Advanced12R1    12.1        121212        555555
>   Basic12R1   12.1        343434        555555
>   Basic12R1 Patch 12.1 to 12.2        343434        555555

When I install in the following order, the results are:

> 1. Advanced12R1 → Basic12R1       Installed
> 2. Basic12R1 → Advanced12R1       Installed
> 3. Basic12R1 → Basic12R1 Patch        Installed
> 4. Basic12R1 + Basic12R1 Patch → Advanced12R1 Not Installed      ※This prompts a mesesage something like "The latest version of the product
>      has been already installed".

My question is why Advanced12R1 can not be installed when Basic12R1 and Basic12R1 Patch have been already installed.
They have the same upgrade code but different product code. What could be the cuase for this? Is there any workaround?

Comment: @Christopher Painter: Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer that I got:

The product version remains same for Advanced12R1 and Basic12R1 Patch. Hence you get the error while trying to install Advanced12R1 when Basic12R1 patch is already being installed

Workaround:
Change the version number of Advanced12R1 to say 12.2 and then install